# Как правильно передать данные между файлами

Tags: javascript, node.js

файл ConnectToDB

```
var pg = require("pg");

var pool = new pg.Pool({
    host: "localhost",
    port: "5432",
    user: "postgres",
    password: "111111",
    database: "hrs"
});

pool.connect(function (err,client,done) {
    if(err)console.log("connect "  + err.toString());

    else
        client.query('SELECT id, "idName", "idContact", "idExperience", 
"idSkill", "dateAdded", "dateColloquy"' +
    'FROM public."applicant ";',function (err,result) {

            if(err) {
                //console.log("query " + err.toString());
                exports.res = "Data NOT";
            }
            else {
                console.log(result.rows);
                module.exports.resul = result.rows;
            }
            done();
        });

});
pool.end()
```

файл app.js

```
var dataWithDB = require('./DataBase/ConnectToDb');

console.log(dataWithDB + "  wit DB");
```

в итоге выводит мне undefined  wit DB

Что я не правильно делаю?

Comment: Что такое ``dataWithDB``?

Comment: Все, исправил.ю=.

Comment: А что Вы ожидаете увидеть в переменной `dataWithDB`?

Comment: Информации из базы данных, я же сделал запрос на поля таблици.